# XML Response Received is Gibberish

Tags: xml, http, flutter, dart

I'm trying to parse this RSS feed's XML response (its content is in **Hebrew**): http://rcs.mako.co.il/rss/food-recipes.xml

In order to do that I make an HTTP request:

```
final response = await http.get(
          "http://rcs.mako.co.il/rss/food-recipes.xml",
          headers: {"Content-type": "text/xml; charset=utf-8"}
        );
```

My problem is that instead of getting the response with its original content, I get it with gibberish (within the **body** attribute):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<rss version="2.0">
  <channel>
    <title>×××× - ××ª××× ×× ×××¨××××ª</title>
    <link>https://www.mako.co.il/food-recipes</link>
    <description>×××× - ××ª××× ×× ×××¨××××ª</description>
    <language>he</language>
    <item>
      <title>××× ×××× ×× ×¤××¦× ××××¨×, ××× ×©××¨×× ×××× ××××</title>
      <description>××××¦×§? ×¨× ×× ×¢×× ×©××× ×××¨×× ××××&lt;p&gt;&lt;img src=&apos;https://img.mako.co.il/2020/03/17/pizzaKAIMG_0864_a.jpg&apos;/&gt;&lt;/p&gt;</description>
      <link>https://www.mako.co.il/food-recipes/recipes_column-bread/Recipe-efa076581b9e071027.htm?Partner=rss</link>
      <pubDate>Thu, 19 Mar 2020 07:19:00 +0200</pubDate>
      <guid>efa076581b9e0710VgnVCM100000700a10acRCRD</guid>
      <shortDescription>××××¦×§? ×¨× ×× ×¢×× ×©××× ×××¨×× ××××</shortDescription>
      <image>https://img.mako.co.il/2020/03/17/pizzaKAIMG_0864_a.jpg</image>
      <image139X80>https://img.mako.co.il/2020/03/17/pizzaKAIMG_0864_f.jpg</image139X80>
      <image435X329>https://img.mako.co.il/2020/03/17/pizzaKAIMG_0864_c.jpg</image435X329>
      <image624X383>https://img.mako.co.il/2020/03/17/pizzaKAIMG_0864_i.jpg</image624X383>
      <photographer>×§×¨× ×××</photographer>
    </item>
    <item>
      <title>××© ×××¨ ×××, ×××× ××¢×× ×××××: ××××ª× ××× ×××¦××</title>
      <description>×××ª××× ×××¡××¡× ××× ××× ×©×ª××¦×× ×××××ª× ×××¢×× ××ª&lt;p&gt;&lt;img src=&apos;https://img.mako.co.il/2020/01/06/VEGAN_CHAVITA_ORI_SHAVIT_a.jpg&apos;/&gt;&lt;/p&gt;</description>
      <link>https://www.mako.co.il/food-recipes/recipes_column-30-minutes/Recipe-5cb7486ed9a7f61027.htm?Partner=rss</link>
      <pubDate>Thu, 19 Mar 2020 06:02:00 +0200</pubDate>
      <guid>5cb7486ed9a7f610VgnVCM100000700a10acRCRD</guid>
      <shortDescription>×××ª××× ×××¡××¡× ××× ××× ×©×ª××¦×× ×××××ª× ×××¢×× ××ª</shortDescription>
      <image>https://img.mako.co.il/2020/01/06/VEGAN_CHAVITA_ORI_SHAVIT_a.jpg</image>
      <image139X80>https://img.mako.co.il/2020/01/06/VEGAN_CHAVITA_ORI_SHAVIT_f.jpg</image139X80>
      <image435X329>https://img.mako.co.il/2020/01/06/VEGAN_CHAVITA_ORI_SHAVIT_c.jpg</image435X329>
      <image624X383>https://img.mako.co.il/2020/01/06/VEGAN_CHAVITA_ORI_SHAVIT_i.jpg</image624X383>
      <photographer>×××¨× ×©×××</photographer>
    </item>
    <item>
      <title>××ª×× × ×× ×××××? ××× × ××× ××××¨× ×× ×¨××× ×××©××××</title>
      <description>×¨×§ ×©××× ××¦× ×¢×× ××××¨××, ×©×××× ××× ×× ××××¨×&lt;p&gt;&lt;img src=&apos;https://img.mako.co.il/2020/03/04/quaker_energyballIMG_0734_a.jpg&apos;/&gt;&lt;/p&gt;</description>
      <link>https://www.mako.co.il/food-recipes/recipes_column-healthy/Recipe-0fd289d29a5a071026.htm?Partner=rss</link>
      <pubDate>Wed, 18 Mar 2020 07:24:00 +0200</pubDate>
      <guid>0fd289d29a5a0710VgnVCM200000650a10acRCRD</guid>
      <shortDescription>×¨×§ ×©××× ××¦× ×¢×× ××××¨××, ×©×××× ××× ×× ××××¨×</shortDescription>
      <image>https://img.mako.co.il/2020/03/04/quaker_energyballIMG_0734_a.jpg</image>
      <image139X80>https://img.mako.co.il/2020/03/04/quaker_energyballIMG_0734_f.jpg</image139X80>
      <image435X329>https://img.mako.co.il/2020/03/04/quaker_energyballIMG_0734_c.jpg</image435X329>
      <image624X383>https://img.mako.co.il/2020/03/04/quaker_energyballIMG_0734_i.jpg</image624X383>
      <photographer>×¨×× ×××× × ××</photographer>
    </item>
    <item>
      <title>×§××× ××ª ×××¡× ×××××ª× ××××¤×× × ×©×××¨××£ ××ª ××¨×©×ª</title>
      <description>×× × ×××©××ª×ª ××××¤××ª ×©×¡×× ×©× ×××× × ××ª ×¢×¦××&lt;p&gt;&lt;img src=&apos;https://img.mako.co.il/2020/03/16/TOST_HAVITA2_a.jpg&apos;/&gt;&lt;/p&gt;</description>
      <link>https://www.mako.co.il/food-recipes/recipes_column-bread/Recipe-a903cb9de52e071026.htm?Partner=rss</link>
      <pubDate>Tue, 17 Mar 2020 07:00:00 +0200</pubDate>
      <guid>a903cb9de52e0710VgnVCM200000650a10acRCRD</guid>
      <shortDescription>×× × ×××©××ª×ª ××××¤××ª ×©×¡×× ×©× ×××× × ××ª ×¢×¦××</shortDescription>
      <image>https://img.mako.co.il/2020/03/16/TOST_HAVITA2_a.jpg</image>
      <image139X80>https://img.mako.co.il/2020/03/16/TOST_HAVITA2_f.jpg</image139X80>
      <image435X329>https://img.mako.co.il/2020/03/16/TOST_HAVITA2_c.jpg</image435X329>
      <image624X383>https://img.mako.co.il/2020/03/16/TOST_HAVITA2_i.jpg</image624X383>
      <photographer>×¨×× ×××× × ××</photographer>
    </item>
    <item>
      <title>××¨×××ª ××¦××¨××× ×©× ××××: ×§×¦××¦××ª ×§××¤××××</title>
      <description>×©××× ×× ××× ××§×¦××¦××ª ×××× ×××××ª?&lt;p&gt;&lt;img src=&apos;https://img.mako.co.il/2020/03/15/89840581_626359704763655_6478026342796361728_n_a.jpg&apos;/&gt;&lt;/p&gt;</description>
      <link>https://www.mako.co.il/food-recipes/recipes_column-meat/Recipe-cc40f835e3fd071026.htm?Partner=rss</link>
      <pubDate>Mon, 16 Mar 2020 07:12:00 +0200</pubDate>
      <guid>cc40f835e3fd0710VgnVCM200000650a10acRCRD</guid>
      <shortDescription>×©××× ×× ××× ××§×¦××¦××ª ×××× ×××××ª?</shortDescription>
      <image>https://img.mako.co.il/2020/03/15/89840581_626359704763655_6478026342796361728_n_a.jpg</image>
      <image139X80>https://img.mako.co.il/2020/03/15/89840581_626359704763655_6478026342796361728_n_f.jpg</image139X80>
      <image435X329>https://img.mako.co.il/2020/03/15/89840581_626359704763655_6478026342796361728_n_c.jpg</image435X329>
      <image624X383>https://img.mako.co.il/2020/03/15/89840581_626359704763655_6478026342796361728_n_i.jpg</image624X383>
      <photographer>××¤×¨×ª ×&apos;×¨××¤×</photographer>
    </item>
    <item>
      <title>×ª×§××¢×× ××××ª? ×ª××× × ×¢×××××ª ××¨× ××× ×¢× ×§×××ª!</title>
      <description>×× ×¦××× ××ª ×××× ×¢× ×××××× ××××ª ××× ××× ×××¢××&lt;p&gt;&lt;img src=&apos;https://img.mako.co.il/2020/03/04/quaker_cookies_ronyoIMG_0772_a.jpg&apos;/&gt;&lt;/p&gt;</description>
      <link>https://www.mako.co.il/food-recipes/recipes_column-cakes/Recipe-301bfee6265a071026.htm?Partner=rss</link>
      <pubDate>Mon, 16 Mar 2020 07:09:00 +0200</pubDate>
      <guid>301bfee6265a0710VgnVCM200000650a10acRCRD</guid>
      <shortDescription>×× ×¦××× ××ª ×××× ×¢× ×××××× ××××ª ××× ××× ×××¢××</shortDescription>
      <image>https://img.mako.co.il/2020/03/04/quaker_cookies_ronyoIMG_0772_a.jpg</image>
      <image139X80>https://img.mako.co.il/2020/03/04/quaker_cookies_ronyoIMG_0772_f.jpg</image139X80>
      <image435X329>https://img.mako.co.il/2020/03/04/quaker_cookies_ronyoIMG_0772_c.jpg</image435X329>
      <image624X383>https://img.mako.co.il/2020/03/04/quaker_cookies_ronyoIMG_0772_i.jpg</image624X383>
      <photographer>×¨×× ×××× × ××</photographer>
    </item>
    <item>
      <title>××× ×¢×××× ××× ×× × ×¤×¨××¡× ××××ª ×××× ×, ×× ××¨××¨</title>
      <description>×¢×××ª ×©××© ×©××× ×× ×¢×××ª ×ª×¤×××× ××××××&lt;p&gt;&lt;img src=&apos;https://img.mako.co.il/2020/03/11/shashapplesIMG_0518_a.jpg&apos;/&gt;&lt;/p&gt;</description>
      <link>https://www.mako.co.il/food-recipes/recipes_column-cakes/Recipe-8a8826fd529c071027.htm?Partner=rss</link>
      <pubDate>Thu, 12 Mar 2020 07:14:00 +0200</pubDate>
      <guid>8a8826fd529c0710VgnVCM100000700a10acRCRD</guid>
      <shortDescription>×¢×××ª ×©××© ×©××× ×× ×¢×××ª ×ª×¤×××× ××××××</shortDescription>
      <image>https://img.mako.co.il/2020/03/11/shashapplesIMG_0518_a.jpg</image>
      <image139X80>https://img.mako.co.il/2020/03/11/shashapplesIMG_0518_f.jpg</image139X80>
      <image435X329>https://img.mako.co.il/2020/03/11/shashapplesIMG_0518_c.jpg</image435X329>
      <image624X383>https://img.mako.co.il/2020/03/11/shashapplesIMG_0518_i.jpg</image624X383>
      <photographer>×§×¨× ×××</photographer>
    </item>
    <item>
      <title>××× ×× ××× ×¤××××××ª ××× ××××¨× ××××¨ ×××</title>
      <description>××××ª ××¡×¤×¦××¤××ª ×× ××¢××× ××¨×××ª ×××¨××ª&lt;p&gt;&lt;img src=&apos;https://img.mako.co.il/2020/03/08/17dayslazagne_a.jpg&apos;/&gt;&lt;/p&gt;</description>
      <link>https://www.mako.co.il/food-recipes/recipes_column-gluten-free/Recipe-a5d628ad7a9b071026.htm?Partner=rss</link>
      <pubDate>Tue, 10 Mar 2020 08:53:00 +0200</pubDate>
      <guid>a5d628ad7a9b0710VgnVCM200000650a10acRCRD</guid>
      <shortDescription>××××ª ××¡×¤×¦××¤××ª ×× ××¢××× ××¨×××ª ×××¨××ª</shortDescription>
      <image>https://img.mako.co.il/2020/03/08/17dayslazagne_a.jpg</image>
      <image139X80>https://img.mako.co.il/2020/03/08/17dayslazagne_f.jpg</image139X80>
      <image435X329>https://img.mako.co.il/2020/03/08/17dayslazagne_c.jpg</image435X329>
      <image624X383>https://img.mako.co.il/2020/03/08/17dayslazagne_i.jpg</image624X383>
      <photographer>×××××¨ ×¨× ×××</photographer>
    </item>
    <item>
      <title>×ª×©××× ××× ×× ×©×××¢×ª× ×¢× ×¡×× ×××××××¨×£ ××××××××</title>
      <description>×§××× ××ª ×××××××¨×£ ×× ×× ×ª× × ××× ×× ×©×× ×× ×©× ××××&lt;p&gt;&lt;img src=&apos;https://img.mako.co.il/2020/03/05/waldorf_yogev26.2.200633_a.jpg&apos;/&gt;&lt;/p&gt;</description>
      <link>https://www.mako.co.il/food-recipes/recipes_column-salads/Recipe-4a91f077d8aa071026.htm?Partner=rss</link>
      <pubDate>Sun, 08 Mar 2020 07:03:00 +0200</pubDate>
      <guid>4a91f077d8aa0710VgnVCM200000650a10acRCRD</guid>
      <shortDescription>×§××× ××ª ×××××××¨×£ ×× ×× ×ª× × ××× ×× ×©×× ×× ×©× ××××</shortDescription>
      <image>https://img.mako.co.il/2020/03/05/waldorf_yogev26.2.200633_a.jpg</image>
      <image139X80>https://img.mako.co.il/2020/03/05/waldorf_yogev26.2.200633_f.jpg</image139X80>
      <image435X329>https://img.mako.co.il/2020/03/05/waldorf_yogev26.2.200633_c.jpg</image435X329>
      <image624X383>https://img.mako.co.il/2020/03/05/waldorf_yogev26.2.200633_i.jpg</image624X383>
      <photographer>××××¨ ×× ××</photographer>
    </item>
    <item>
      <title>××¢×××××ª ××¨××× ×××× ××© ××ª×××ª ×¡××</title>
      <description>×× ×ª××× ×××××, × ××× ××ª×× ×× ××××× ××××&lt;p&gt;&lt;img src=&apos;https://img.mako.co.il/2020/01/09/P1980863_a.jpg&apos;/&gt;&lt;/p&gt;</description>
      <link>https://www.mako.co.il/food-recipes/recipes_column-cakes/Recipe-5cfaa737a6a8f61027.htm?Partner=rss</link>
      <pubDate>Thu, 05 Mar 2020 07:19:00 +0200</pubDate>
      <guid>5cfaa737a6a8f610VgnVCM100000700a10acRCRD</guid>
      <shortDescription>×× ×ª××× ×××××, × ××× ××ª×× ×× ××××× ××××</shortDescription>
      <image>https://img.mako.co.il/2020/01/09/P1980863_a.jpg</image>
      <image139X80>https://img.mako.co.il/2020/01/09/P1980863_f.jpg</image139X80>
      <image435X329>https://img.mako.co.il/2020/01/09/P1980863_c.jpg</image435X329>
      <image624X383>https://img.mako.co.il/2020/01/09/P1980863_i.jpg</image624X383>
      <photographer>×××¨× ×©×××</photographer>
    </item>
    <item>
      <title>×××× ×××ª ×©××§××× ×¦&apos;××¤×¡ ×××¨××¤××ª ××©××ª</title>
      <description>×××ª×¨ ××× ××× ×××¨×××ª ×××§×¨ ×©××ª - ×¤×©×× ×××&lt;p&gt;&lt;img src=&apos;https://img.mako.co.il/2020/03/04/ROHAV_lahmaniotCCIMG_0092_a.jpg&apos;/&gt;&lt;/p&gt;</description>
      <link>https://www.mako.co.il/food-recipes/recipes_column-cakes/Recipe-e6c997d5045a071026.htm?Partner=rss</link>
      <pubDate>Thu, 05 Mar 2020 07:12:00 +0200</pubDate>
      <guid>e6c997d5045a0710VgnVCM200000650a10acRCRD</guid>
      <shortDescription>×××ª×¨ ××× ××× ×××¨×××ª ×××§×¨ ×©××ª - ×¤×©×× ×××</shortDescription>
      <image>https://img.mako.co.il/2020/03/04/ROHAV_lahmaniotCCIMG_0092_a.jpg</image>
      <image139X80>https://img.mako.co.il/2020/03/04/ROHAV_lahmaniotCCIMG_0092_f.jpg</image139X80>
      <image435X329>https://img.mako.co.il/2020/03/04/ROHAV_lahmaniotCCIMG_0092_c.jpg</image435X329>
      <image624X383>https://img.mako.co.il/2020/03/04/ROHAV_lahmaniotCCIMG_0092_i.jpg</image624X383>
      <photographer>×§×¨× ×××</photographer>
    </item>
    <item>
      <title>××©×× × ×××ª×: ×××ª××× ××××× × ×××× ×©× ×¨×××××</title>
      <description>×× ×× ××©× × ×× ××××××, ×××¦×§ ×××× ×××××ª ××¢×××&lt;p&gt;&lt;img src=&apos;https://img.mako.co.il/2020/03/01/erezbenshahar_haman2020_recipe_a.jpg&apos;/&gt;&lt;/p&gt;</description>
      <link>https://www.mako.co.il/food-recipes/recipes_column-holidays/Recipe-36dbad97f169071027.htm?Partner=rss</link>
      <pubDate>Wed, 04 Mar 2020 07:18:00 +0200</pubDate>
      <guid>36dbad97f1690710VgnVCM100000700a10acRCRD</guid>
      <shortDescription>×× ×× ××©× × ×× ××××××, ×××¦×§ ×××× ×××××ª ××¢×××</shortDescription>
      <image>https://img.mako.co.il/2020/03/01/erezbenshahar_haman2020_recipe_a.jpg</image>
      <image139X80>https://img.mako.co.il/2020/03/01/erezbenshahar_haman2020_recipe_f.jpg</image139X80>
      <image435X329>https://img.mako.co.il/2020/03/01/erezbenshahar_haman2020_recipe_c.jpg</image435X329>
      <image624X383>https://img.mako.co.il/2020/03/01/erezbenshahar_haman2020_recipe_i.jpg</image624X383>
      <photographer>××¨× ×× ×©××¨</photographer>
    </item>
    <item>
      <title>××¦×× × ××¨× ×¤× ××¡×××ª ××©××¨× ××ª ×××××¡× ×©× ××××§×¨</title>
      <description>×× ×××× ×©× ××××¡×ª ×§××××§×¨ ×¢× ×× ××××£ ×©× ×¤××&lt;p&gt;&lt;img src=&apos;https://img.mako.co.il/2020/03/03/DAISA_APLLEPIE_a.jpg&apos;/&gt;&lt;/p&gt;</description>
      <link>https://www.mako.co.il/food-recipes/recipes_column-healthy/Recipe-7f5118535df9071026.htm?Partner=rss</link>
      <pubDate>Wed, 04 Mar 2020 07:00:00 +0200</pubDate>
      <guid>7f5118535df90710VgnVCM200000650a10acRCRD</guid>
      <shortDescription>×× ×××× ×©× ××××¡×ª ×§××××§×¨ ×¢× ×× ××××£ ×©× ×¤××</shortDescription>
      <image>https://img.mako.co.il/2020/03/03/DAISA_APLLEPIE_a.jpg</image>
      <image139X80>https://img.mako.co.il/2020/03/03/DAISA_APLLEPIE_f.jpg</image139X80>
      <image435X329>https://img.mako.co.il/2020/03/03/DAISA_APLLEPIE_c.jpg</image435X329>
      <image624X383>https://img.mako.co.il/2020/03/03/DAISA_APLLEPIE_i.jpg</image624X383>
      <photographer>×¨×× ×××× × ××</photographer>
    </item>
    <item>
      <title>××××¤ ××§×× ×©×©×× × ×× × ××ª ××©× ××¦× ××§×¦× ××§×¦×</title>
      <description>××¤× × ×©××ª× ××¨×××× ××× ××ª× ×××××× ×× ×¡××ª ××××ª!&lt;p&gt;&lt;img src=&apos;https://img.mako.co.il/2020/03/01/20200210_120445_a.jpg&apos;/&gt;&lt;/p&gt;</description>
      <link>https://www.mako.co.il/food-recipes/recipes_column-chicken/Recipe-66843b143d59071027.htm?Partner=rss</link>
      <pubDate>Tue, 03 Mar 2020 07:14:00 +0200</pubDate>
      <guid>66843b143d590710VgnVCM100000700a10acRCRD</guid>
      <shortDescription>××¤× × ×©××ª× ××¨×××× ××× ××ª× ×××××× ×× ×¡××ª ××××ª!</shortDescription>
      <image>https://img.mako.co.il/2020/03/01/20200210_120445_a.jpg</image>
      <image139X80>https://img.mako.co.il/2020/03/01/20200210_120445_f.jpg</image139X80>
      <image435X329>https://img.mako.co.il/2020/03/01/20200210_120445_c.jpg</image435X329>
      <image624X383>https://img.mako.co.il/2020/03/01/20200210_120445_i.jpg</image624X383>
      <photographer>×× × ××¨-×× ×©×××¨×¥</photographer>
    </item>
    <item>
      <title>××©××× ××× ××ª ××××©××: ×¢×××××ª ×¢× ×§ ×-6 ××¢×××</title>
      <description>×× ×× ×©××§×× ××× ×××¨ ×××¤×× ××¢××××¤××¦×ª&lt;p&gt;&lt;img src=&apos;https://img.mako.co.il/2020/03/03/IMG_0453_a.jpg&apos;/&gt;&lt;/p&gt;</description>
      <link>https://www.mako.co.il/food-recipes/recipes_column-cakes/Recipe-7f673ed9a269071026.htm?Partner=rss</link>
      <pubDate>Tue, 03 Mar 2020 07:10:00 +0200</pubDate>
      <guid>7f673ed9a2690710VgnVCM200000650a10acRCRD</guid>
      <shortDescription>×× ×× ×©××§×× ××× ×××¨ ×××¤×× ××¢××××¤××¦×ª</shortDescription>
      <image>https://img.mako.co.il/2020/03/03/IMG_0453_a.jpg</image>
      <image139X80>https://img.mako.co.il/2020/03/03/IMG_0453_f.jpg</image139X80>
      <image435X329>https://img.mako.co.il/2020/03/03/IMG_0453_c.jpg</image435X329>
      <image624X383>https://img.mako.co.il/2020/03/03/IMG_0453_i.jpg</image624X383>
      <photographer>×¨×× ×××× × ××</photographer>
    </item>
    <item>
      <title>×××ª ×¢×××ª ××× × ××ª ××××©× ×©×× ×, ×××¤×¢× ×× ××ª×××</title>
      <description>××× ×××ª ×× ×¢×××ª ××× × × ××× ××ª××××ª ×©×¤××©×ª×?&lt;p&gt;&lt;img src=&apos;https://img.mako.co.il/2020/02/26/banana_shaishIMG_9678_a.jpg&apos;/&gt;&lt;/p&gt;</description>
      <link>https://www.mako.co.il/food-recipes/recipes_column-cakes/Recipe-2ddd4aa57718071027.htm?Partner=rss</link>
      <pubDate>Thu, 27 Feb 2020 07:10:00 +0200</pubDate>
      <guid>2ddd4aa577180710VgnVCM100000700a10acRCRD</guid>
      <shortDescription>××× ×××ª ×× ×¢×××ª ××× × × ××× ××ª××××ª ×©×¤××©×ª×?</shortDescription>
      <image>https://img.mako.co.il/2020/02/26/banana_shaishIMG_9678_a.jpg</image>
      <image139X80>https://img.mako.co.il/2020/02/26/banana_shaishIMG_9678_f.jpg</image139X80>
      <image435X329>https://img.mako.co.il/2020/02/26/banana_shaishIMG_9678_c.jpg</image435X329>
      <image624X383>https://img.mako.co.il/2020/02/26/banana_shaishIMG_9678_i.jpg</image624X383>
      <photographer>×§×¨× ×××</photographer>
    </item>
    <item>
      <title>×§××× ×××ª×: ×× ××¡××××ª ××§×¦××¦××ª ×××¢×× ×××ª ××××</title>
      <description>××× ××ª××× ××§×¦××¦××ª ×¢××©×× ×©×××¨××ª ××¤××¨×××ª&lt;p&gt;&lt;img src=&apos;https://img.mako.co.il/2020/01/09/ktsitsotP1980655_a.jpg&apos;/&gt;&lt;/p&gt;</description>
      <link>https://www.mako.co.il/food-recipes/recipes_column-vegetarian-recipes/Recipe-dbc99f869c98f61027.htm?Partner=rss</link>
      <pubDate>Wed, 26 Feb 2020 19:43:00 +0200</pubDate>
      <guid>dbc99f869c98f610VgnVCM100000700a10acRCRD</guid>
      <shortDescription>××× ××ª××× ××§×¦××¦××ª ×¢××©×× ×©×××¨××ª ××¤××¨×××ª</shortDescription>
      <image>https://img.mako.co.il/2020/01/09/ktsitsotP1980655_a.jpg</image>
      <image139X80>https://img.mako.co.il/2020/01/09/ktsitsotP1980655_f.jpg</image139X80>
      <image435X329>https://img.mako.co.il/2020/01/09/ktsitsotP1980655_c.jpg</image435X329>
      <image624X383>https://img.mako.co.il/2020/01/09/ktsitsotP1980655_i.jpg</image624X383>
      <photographer>×××¨× ×©×××</photographer>
    </item>
    <item>
      <title>××ª ××©×§×©××§× ××× ×××× ×××× ×× ×¨×§ ××©× × ××¨×××××</title>
      <description>×¨×§ ×ª×§×¤××× ×©××©× ××× ×××× ×××× ××¡×¤××§ ×××××ª×××&lt;p&gt;&lt;img src=&apos;https://img.mako.co.il/2020/02/20/shutterstock_586573883_a.jpg&apos;/&gt;&lt;/p&gt;</description>
      <link>https://www.mako.co.il/food-recipes/recipes_column-one-pot-meal/Recipe-664a6ed7d567071027.htm?Partner=rss</link>
      <pubDate>Tue, 25 Feb 2020 07:14:00 +0200</pubDate>
      <guid>664a6ed7d5670710VgnVCM100000700a10acRCRD</guid>
      <shortDescription>×¨×§ ×ª×§×¤××× ×©××©× ××× ×××× ×××× ××¡×¤××§ ×××××ª×××</shortDescription>
      <image>https://img.mako.co.il/2020/02/20/shutterstock_586573883_a.jpg</image>
      <image139X80>https://img.mako.co.il/2020/02/20/shutterstock_586573883_f.jpg</image139X80>
      <image435X329>https://img.mako.co.il/2020/02/20/shutterstock_586573883_c.jpg</image435X329>
      <image624X383>https://img.mako.co.il/2020/02/20/shutterstock_586573883_i.jpg</image624X383>
      <photographer>j.chizhe</photographer>
    </item>
    <item>
      <title>×××××× ×××ª× ×©×× ×ª×¦×××× ×××¤×¡××§ ×× ×©× ×©</title>
      <description>×××¤××× ××× ×× ×¨×× ××§××&lt;p&gt;&lt;img src=&apos;https://img.mako.co.il/2020/02/23/IMG_8618_a.jpg&apos;/&gt;&lt;/p&gt;</description>
      <link>https://www.mako.co.il/food-recipes/recipes_column-gluten-free/Recipe-5acbcb0abe17071027.htm?Partner=rss</link>
      <pubDate>Tue, 25 Feb 2020 07:00:00 +0200</pubDate>
      <guid>5acbcb0abe170710VgnVCM100000700a10acRCRD</guid>
      <shortDescription>×××¤××× ××× ×× ×¨×× ××§××</shortDescription>
      <image>https://img.mako.co.il/2020/02/23/IMG_8618_a.jpg</image>
      <image139X80>https://img.mako.co.il/2020/02/23/IMG_8618_f.jpg</image139X80>
      <image435X329>https://img.mako.co.il/2020/02/23/IMG_8618_c.jpg</image435X329>
      <image624X383>https://img.mako.co.il/2020/02/23/IMG_8618_i.jpg</image624X383>
      <photographer>×¨×× ×××× × ××</photographer>
    </item>
    <item>
      <title>×××¡×§××××××, ×§×¨× ××ª××ª××: ××¢××× ×©×× × ××¡××¤&quot;×©</title>
      <description>×× ××¤×× ×©××¨××© ××× × ×©×ª× ×ª×× ×××ª ×©× ××××¤× ×××?&lt;p&gt;&lt;img src=&apos;https://img.mako.co.il/2020/02/19/tutim_ron_yo_a.jpg&apos;/&gt;&lt;/p&gt;</description>
      <link>https://www.mako.co.il/food-recipes/recipes_column-cakes/Recipe-39d4b82d1ac5071026.htm?Partner=rss</link>
      <pubDate>Thu, 20 Feb 2020 14:00:00 +0200</pubDate>
      <guid>39d4b82d1ac50710VgnVCM200000650a10acRCRD</guid>
      <shortDescription>×× ××¤×× ×©××¨××© ××× × ×©×ª× ×ª×× ×××ª ×©× ××××¤× ×××?</shortDescription>
      <image>https://img.mako.co.il/2020/02/19/tutim_ron_yo_a.jpg</image>
      <image139X80>https://img.mako.co.il/2020/02/19/tutim_ron_yo_f.jpg</image139X80>
      <image435X329>https://img.mako.co.il/2020/02/19/tutim_ron_yo_c.jpg</image435X329>
      <image624X383>https://img.mako.co.il/2020/02/19/tutim_ron_yo_i.jpg</image624X383>
      <photographer>×¨×× ×××× × ××</photographer>
    </item>
  </channel>
</rss>
```

**This is how it looks like after parsing the content to a list:**

[image]

How can I fix it?

Comment: @pskink Yes. In Hebrew.

Comment: @pskink I tried to parse it to a list but it stays the same. After I have the response I use the Dart XML package in order to parse the content.

Comment: It's probably Mojibake

Comment: @pskink text/xml

Comment: and i suppose you are using [body](https://pub.dev/documentation/http/latest/http/Response/body.html) property? the docs say: *"The body of the response as a string.

This is converted from bodyBytes using the charset parameter of the Content-Type header field, if available. If it's unavailable or if the encoding name is unknown, latin1 is used by default, as per RFC 2616."* - maybe you should encode [bodyBytes](https://pub.dev/documentation/http/latest/http/Response/bodyBytes.html) by yourself?

Comment: ...looking at a (browser) response, it is `gzip` encoded...which dart should actually "auto-support" (https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-io/HttpClient/autoUncompress.html) ..the issue could also be "between get and output"(!?)

Comment: @pskink Can you share an example which shows how to encode the bodyBytes by myself?

Comment: @xerx593 What do you mean by "between get and output"?

Comment: ..i mean: (maybe) `response` is ok...but in further processing ..it appears gibberish(!?)

Comment: @xerx593 I don't make any further processing on the response. The one attached is the one I get from the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the server does not set the response charset in the format the HTTP library expects it. `response.body` wrongly decodes the response data as *Latin1*.

If you can't fix the server, the following code manually decodes the raw data as *UTF-8* and works for me:

```dart
final response = await http.get("http://rcs.mako.co.il/rss/food-recipes.xml");
final body = Utf8Decoder().convert(response.bodyBytes);
final document = xml.parse(body);
print(document.toString());
```